# How to place the custom form in drupal 8 paragraphs?

Tags: drupal-8

I have a custom form. I need to place the custom form in paragraphs as component.

I have tried in this way,

function hook_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {

$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\custom_module\Form\CustomModuleForm');

$variables['custom_form'] = $form;

}

And trying to print the value in the paragraph twig file.
Its not printing. Please help on this!